# How to use switch in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$oride='';
$count = "25";
$origin = $_POST["origin"];
$destinataion = $_POST["destination"];
$oride = ($destination = $_POST["destination"] - $origin= $_POST["origin"]);

    switch (true) {
    case ($count<="0"):
    echo "invalid";
        break;

    case ($count==="15"):
    echo $count;
        break;

    case ($count==="16"):
    $total = $count + "1";
    echo $total;
        break;
    default:
        echo "hello";
}  }
```

The code will compute 1st then execute switch depending on what is the           result of the computation. I tried if else but it will be too long because the case will go up to 130.

Comment: Your $count is a string, whatever else aside I'm fairly confident you want it to be an int.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the var $count  in switch statement  and the constant in case  this way

```
   switch ($count) {
    case  "0" :
    echo "invalid";
        break;

    case "15":
    echo $count;
        break;

    case "16":
    $total = $count + "1";
    echo $total;
        break;
    default:
        echo "hello";
        break;
  }
```

Comment: thank you bro this worked for me. . .now how to include a case when the $count is below 0

Comment: @JericJavier use an `if` in the default case (or outside the switch)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an expression to the `switch` statement, while the case statements are just "versions" of the result of that expression. The only thing you can NOT do directly is the "<= 0" expression, but you can work around it:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$oride='';
$count = "25";
$origin = $_POST["origin"];
$destinataion = $_POST["destination"];
$oride = ($destination = $_POST["destination"] - $origin= $_POST["origin"]);

// --- normalize $count:
$count = $count <= 0 ? 0 : $count;

// use $count as expression:
    switch ($count) {
    case 0:
    echo "invalid";
        break;

    case "15":
    echo $count;
        break;

    case "16":
    $total = $count + "1";
    echo $total;
        break;
    default:
        echo "hello";
}  }
```